# Styles for multiple breakpoints in SASS

Tags: sass, media-queries, mixins

I've defined two mixins in SASS that allow me to place media queries easily. The problem I'm encountering is that I'm repeating myself frequently across many queries. That is to say, some of my style changes are the same for tablet and mobile breakpoints and others are different. Example:

```
.foo
  float: left
  width: 50%
  +tablet()
    float: none
    display: block
    width: 100%
  +mobile()
    float: none
    display: block
    width: 100%
```

Where my mixins are defined like this:

```
=tablet
  @media (min-width: #{$mobile-width} + 1) and (max-width: #{$tablet-width})
    @content

=mobile
  @media (max-width: #{$mobile-width})
    @content
```

I'd love to do something like this:

```
...
+tablet(), +mobile
  float: none
  display: block
  width: 100%
```

That doesn't compile, so what is the best way to keep my SASS stylesheets DRY?

Comment: You could define another mixin with only max-width: #{$tablet-width} to get both together.

Comment: For future projects maybe you could go mobile first to get around this problem. You would not define a Media-Query for mobile - but for all viewports going up e.g. tablet and desktop and not define a max-width. Your normal Code would be for mobile and if something was changed for tablet or desktop you could just overwrite it for all higher viewports.

Comment: @StefanF. Great suggestion - I may create a mixin called +both(). Add that as answer if you'd like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Stefan F's comment, the easiest thing to do in this case was to create a third mixin called (something like): `+both()` which encapsulated the mobile and tablet sizing. (I'm answering this myself only because he did not and it has been some time.)

Example:

```
=both
  @media (max-width: #{$tablet-width})
    @content
```

Usage:

```
.foo
  float: left
  width: 50%
  +both()
    float: none
    display: block
    width: 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define mobile and tablet medias as strings and then concatenate these strings.

Scss can be easily converted to sass.

```
$mobile-width: 320px;
$tablet-width: 760px;

// Media queries as strings
$tablet: "(min-width: #{$mobile-width + 1}) and (max-width: #{$tablet-width})";
$mobile: "(max-width: #{$mobile-width})";

// Converts a list to a string with delimiters between elements
@function join-list($list, $separator: ", ") {
  $result-string: "";

  @each $item in $list {
    // Index of the current item of `$list` list
    $index: index($list, $item);
    $result-string: $result-string + $item;

    // If this is not the last item, adds separator
    @if ($index != length($list)) {
      $result-string: $result-string + $separator;
    }
  }

  @return $result-string;
}

@mixin get-media($medias...) {
  @media #{join-list($medias, " and ")} {
    @content;
  }
}

.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;

  @include get-media($mobile, $tablet) {
  // or @include get-media($mobile) {
  // or @include get-media($tablet) {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Css output:

```
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 320px) and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 760px) {
  .foo {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

SassMeister [demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/91e54d38734e28e143afa6714321a4d8).